# Get multiple inputs to QRCode

Tags: php, qr-code

I have a website that converts the input texts to QRcode. The problem is that I can only get access to the first input text. For example I have this code:

**Page1.php**

```
<form action="getForm.php" method="post">        
    <input type="text" id="text1id" name="Text1"> //I have access
    <input type="number" id="text2id" name="text2"> <br><br> //I dont have access
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_y">
</form>
```

I only have access to the first "Text1" because I dont know hot to pass two variables to qr code. This is the code of the qrcode

**getForm.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_y'])) {
    include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
    $text=$_POST['Text1'];

    //I tried to put here the POST of Text2
    $folder="images/";
    $file_name="qr.png";
    $file_name=$folder.$file_name;
    QRcode::png($text,$file_name);
    echo"<img src='images/qr.png'>";

    //To Display Code Without Storing
    //QRcode::png($text);
}
```

Comment: Simple: you concatenate them and use the (last) variable from both.

Comment: Can you put an example. Php is not my strong :)

Comment: Hello, sorry to jump in.  If you do echo var_dump($_POST); you can see every thing that is being passed into your php file, I would be surprised if "text2" is not in it.

Comment: I posted something for you below. @Jose since it would have been too long in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: You're most welcome @Jose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign variables to each POST array, then use the one from both to form a third variable from the concatenated ones.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_y']))
    {
        include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
        $text1=$_POST['Text1'];
        $text2=$_POST['text2'];
        $text3 = $text1. "" . $text2; // concatenated from previous 2


        $folder="images/";
        $file_name="qr.png";
        $file_name=$folder.$file_name;
        QRcode::png($text3,$file_name); // used $text3 from the concatenated variables
        echo"<img src='images/qr.png'>";

    //To Display Code Without Storing
    //QRcode::png($text);
    }
```

However, it is best to also check if any of the inputs are empty.

Sidenote:

In this `$text3 = $text1. "" . $text2;` you can add anything inside the `""` as a separator.

I.e.: using an underscore.

```
$text3 = $text1. "_" . $text2;
```

It could also be a space

```
$text3 = $text1. " " . $text2;
```

- The choice is yours.